# How to make a background image repeat horizontally?

Tags: html, web, wysiwyg

```
<div id="background"> <img src="images/Untitled.gif" id="Image5" alt="" style="background-repeat:repeat-y;width:273px;height:68px;"/> </div>
```

I want to make an image repeat in a horizontal direction, I thought I could to this by making it a background image but it isn't working.  tell me what I am doing wrong thanks.

Comment: you can use `background-repeat:repeat-x;` attribute in css .ref:http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeatx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<div style="height: 100px; background-image:url('picture.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
Your text here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it repeat horizontally with a background, but the background needs to be on the container, not the `img` itself. Do something like this:

```
<div style="height: 68px; background: url(image.png);"></div>
```

Comment: Don't forget OP is asking for `repeat-x` as well.

Comment: @Boaz: If it's short enough then it won't get the chance to repeat on the Y axis.

Comment: True, but it cannot be inferred from the question.

Comment: @Boaz: That's why I included an explicit `height`.

Comment: But the height of the image is clearly `68px` in the OP, so with a `100px` high container, the background will most definitely repeat vertically as well.

Comment: @Boaz: The `68px` wasn't there when I answered the question. I updated my answer to make it `68px`.

Comment: `<div style="background-repeat:repeat-y; height: 100px; background: url(Untitled.gif);"></div>` I used this and it is recognized as a background image but it doesn't repeat.

Comment: @Dave: Change `repeat-y` to `repeat-x` or remove the `background-repeat` part altogether; `repeat-y` means to repeat *vertically*, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Dave Note that you're confusing `repeat-x` with `repeat-y`

Comment: I changed it to `repeat-x` my code: `<div style="height: 100px; background-image:url('Untitled.gif'); background-repeat:repeat-x;"></div>` and it still isn't repeating

Comment: well thanks for your help anyway it looks like it may be a problem with my browser or html generator... I tried editing the code after generation but still not working. but thanks anyway. :)